Reading environment Variables from .env as a Python Package
i am currently writing a python Package, that needs API Keys to function properly. I want to give the users the choice weither they want to use the normal os environment variables or use a .env file.
In older Projects i used python-dotenv to load the variables and os.getenv("VARIABLE_NAME") to store the variables into my config object. Unfortunately this does not work, if i tried it after building and downloading the package.
load_dotenv()
variable = os.getenv("VARIABLENAME)

If i run this code with a demo Script that is in the same project everything works fine but if i try to build it and download it in another project that looks like this:
myproject/
├── .env
├── pyproject.toml
└── main.py

it does not load the environment variables from the .env file.
I is always able to download the variables from the os environment variables

What you are asking for is possible directly, though it might be somewhat "advanced Python" - meanwhile, you might take a lookg at the dynaconf project, which allows proper configuration from various sources, including .env files, covering most edge cases: https://www.dynaconf.com/ (dynaconf is Free Software authored and maintained by Bruno Rocha, Python Software Foundation fellow and currently in a role as  Principal Enginner at Redhat. The software is unrelated to RedHat, though)

Thank you very much! So what is "best practice" here? Using this extra dependency? How are bigger Packages managing secrets?
